# How can I select an ID from the row with the maximum value for each of several columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to extract the values of an ID column from the rows containing the maximum values of each of several other columns, and then collate these in a new table which has the column headers in one column and the row IDs of the maximum values in another.

To clarify:

My data is structured like this, extending into a roughly 20x20 grid:

```
table:

 id | name  | A | B | C | D | E | ... 
----|-------|---|---|---|---|---|----
101 | name1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 | ... 
102 | name2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | ... 
103 | name3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | ... 
104 | name4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 | ... 
... | ..... | . | . | . | . | . | ...
```

And I want a query that returns the `name` which contains the highest value for each column `A`, `B`, `C` etc., like so:

```
top_scorers:

id | top_scorer
---|-----------
 A | name1
 B | name1
 C | name4
 D | name2
 E | name4
```

In this case I know the maximum values will all be the same so I can search for values `= 4`, but it might not be in future so finding the max would be a more robust method.

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
SELECT name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE A = 4
UNION
SELECT name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE B = 4
UNION
...
```

And so on, repeating for each column header.

I hoped this would generate the `top_scorer` column above, which I could then join to another table containing the column headers of my original table. However it does not return any `name` more than once, so I only get as many rows are there are distinct entries in the top_scorer column. The resulting values are also sorted alphabetically rather than in the order they're first found.

So rather than

```
top_scorer
----------
name1
name1
name4
name2
name4
```

the code above returns

```
top_scorer
----------
name1
name2
name4
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE A = MAX(A)
UNION
SELECT name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE B = MAX(B)
UNION
...
```

But this gave an error: "misuse of aggregate function MAX()"

Can anyone suggest a query that would return the `top_scorers` table above?

Similar questions I've found are either looking to return maximums from one column using `GROUP BY`, or the maximum value across a range of columns for each row  (equivalent to the highest score achieved by each `name` in this case), which aren't what I'm looking for.

Is there maybe something clever that can be done with `PIVOT` or some other transposing function? I'm a SQL beginner and haven't tried using anything like that before.

This is running on DB Browser for SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach takes advantage of one of sqlite3's documented but non-standard behaviors when [mixing aggregate and non-aggregate results in a query](https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause) - when using `max()`, all non-aggregate values are taken from one of the rows with the maximum value (Ties broken at random):

```
WITH maxes(column, name, maxval) AS
  (SELECT 'A', name, max(A) FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B', name, max(B) FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C', name, max(C) FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'D', name, max(D) FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E', name, max(E) FROM mytable)
SELECT column AS id, name AS top_scorer
FROM maxes
ORDER BY column;
```

which gives

```
id          top_scorer
----------  ----------
A           name1
B           name1
C           name4
D           name2
E           name4
```

---

However, a database design that uses a one-to-many relationship with a second table instead of one column per thing is going to be a better approach.

Consider this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE names(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE scores(name_id INTEGER REFERENCES names(id)
                  , score_id TEXT
                  , val INTEGER
                  , PRIMARY KEY(name_id, score_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

populated with your test data:

```
INSERT INTO names VALUES(101,'name1');
INSERT INTO names VALUES(102,'name2');
INSERT INTO names VALUES(103,'name3');
INSERT INTO names VALUES(104,'name4');
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101,'A',4);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101,'B',4);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101,'C',1);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101,'D',3);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101,'E',3);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(102,'A',3);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(102,'B',1);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(102,'C',2);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(102,'D',4);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(102,'E',2);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(103,'A',2);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(103,'B',2);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(103,'C',3);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(103,'D',2);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(103,'E',1);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(104,'A',1);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(104,'B',3);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(104,'C',4);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(104,'D',1);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES(104,'E',4);
```

you can use this query:

```
WITH maxes AS
 (SELECT score_id, name, max(val)
  FROM names
  JOIN scores ON id = name_id
  GROUP BY score_id)
SELECT score_id AS id, name AS top_scorer
FROM maxes
ORDER BY score_id;
```

which avoids having to hard code each id being tracked like the current one-per-column design you're using. Much, much cleaner and flexible.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. I had wondered whether the easiest way was to restructure the database so all the scores were in one column, and avoiding hard-coding the column names is clearly preferable. Is there a way to automate rearranging the data in SQL into the format you suggest, maybe using CROSS JOIN?

Otherwise I'm looking at ~400 lines like "INSERT INTO scores VALUES(101, 'A', 4);"

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to return a resultset with just the name and one of the columns A, B, C,....
 Then get the result that you want with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with cte as (
  select name, 'A' id, A number from tablename
  union all
  select name, 'B' , B from tablename
  union all
  select name, 'C' , C from tablename
  union all
  select name, 'D' , D from tablename
  union all
  select name, 'E' , E from tablename
  union all
  ............................................
) 
select c.id, c.name top_scorer 
from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where id = c.id and number > c.number
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czzaNbm9hN5LZLCZW1azcT/1).
Results:

```
| id  | top_scorer |
| --- | ---------- |
| A   | name1      |
| B   | name1      |
| C   | name4      |
| D   | name2      |
| E   | name4      |
| .   | .....      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to specify "FOR ALL COLUMNS BUT ..." is sometimes a drag, so here is a (bash) script which, given an SQLite database and table, will produce a table showing the max values by column, as specified in the original question.

```
#!/bin/bash
# 2019.10.21

# To prevent loading ~/.sqliterc specify -init ""
INIT="-init ''"

function help {
    cat <<EOF
Syntax: $0 [OPTIONS] databasefile table [name]

This script will emit a table of max column values for the given table,
except for any columns named `id` or `name`. The output format is:

columnName id_of_top_scorer

where `id_of_top_scorer` is the `name` of the (or a) top scorer.

If `name` is not specified, it defaults to `rowid`.

Requirements:
  sqlite3 on the \$PATH

Options: 
 -h | --help :: this help

EOF
}

while [ "$1" ]
do case "$1" in
      -h | --help | "" ) help
           exit
           ;;
      * ) break
      ;;
  esac
done

function die     { echo "$0: $@" >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

if [ $# = 0 ] ; then die Syntax: "$0 DATABASE table [name]"; fi

db="$1"
shift
if [ ! -s "$db" ] ; then echo "$0 : $db not found" ; exit ; fi

TABLE="$1"
shift
if [ -z "$TABLE" ] ; then help ; exit ; fi

name="$3"
shift
if [ -z "$name" ] ; then name=rowid ; fi

# Global: db name TABLE
function columns {
    local i=0
    local column
    sqlite3 $INIT -readonly "$db" <<< "select name from pragma_table_info( '$TABLE' );" |
    while read -r column ; do
        if [ "$column" = id ] ; then continue ; fi
        if [ "$column" = name ] ; then continue ; fi
        if [ $i = 0 ] ; then echo "("
          else echo "UNION ALL"
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
            echo "SELECT [$column], $name, max([$column]) FROM [$TABLE]"
    done
}

(echo "WITH maxes(column, $name, maxval) AS"
 columns
 cat <<EOF
)
SELECT column AS id, $name AS top_scorer
FROM maxes
ORDER BY column;
EOF
) | sqlite3 $INIT -readonly "$db"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `union all` and a hard-coded column name:

```
SELECT 'A' as id, name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE A = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', name AS top_scorer FROM table
WHERE B = 4
UNION ALL
...
```